# Functionally create associative arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I wish to shorten the amount of code in my PHP file by using a function which creates arrays, however the array contents need to be referencing other array components... so, this code alone works:

```
$array['sql'] = "SQL Statement";
$array['result'] = $db -> query( $array['sql'] );
$array['single'] = $array['result'] -> fetch_assoc();
```

I realise this is fairly hard, but then I had the idea to do this:

```
$array = array( array( 'db_sql1', "SQL Statement 1" ), array( 'db_sql2', "SQL Statement 2" ) );
foreach ( $array as $items ) {
    $$items[0]['sql'] = $items[1];
    $$items[0]['result'] = $db -> query( $$items[0]['sql'] );
    $$items[0]['single'] = $$items[0]['result'] -> fetch_assoc();
}
```

But this doesn't work because (I believe at least), the ['sql'] is being used in order to name the $$items, rather than writing to them. How is it possible (if at all) to do this?

I understand if this is not possible because of whatever reason, but I thought it would be useful to try find out.

Comment: By "functional" did you mean that it "works", and not functional as opposed to imperative?

Comment: You're replying to a question asked two years ago, what was meant has very little bearing now.

Comment: I disagree, a lot of questions asked / answered a decade later still provide value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes if you use arrays combined with [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) you need to tell PHP if the index/key is now for the variable name, or to access the variable itself. To clarify this just use `{}`, e.g.

```
$array = array( array( 'db_sql1', "SQL Statement 1" ), array( 'db_sql2', "SQL Statement 2" ) );

foreach ( $array as $items ) {
    ${$items[0]}['sql'] = $items[1];
    ${$items[0]}['result'] = $db -> query( ${$items[0]}['sql'] );
    ${$items[0]}['single'] = ${$items[0]}['result'] -> fetch_assoc();
}
```

---

**Side note:**

With using curly brackets you also make your code for PHP 7 backwards compatible, since from PHP 5 to 7 the right-to-left evaluation will change to left-to-right as you can see here: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling

Comment: Thank you, gloriously simple solution that I failed to find... incredible. Additionally thank you for your excellent speed, I have to wait 8 minutes to accept your answer!

Comment: @lsrwLuke You're welcome. Have a nice day :D (BTW: updated the answer to show that the curly brackets have additional advantages)

Comment: that is not functional

Comment: This is functional, it carries out the code in operation, as opposed to after specifically declaring everything.